# Problem Condition and Algorithm Stability

Tags: algorithms, stability, error-estimation, condition-number

Consider 2 mathematical problems:

$$
f_1(x) = a - x \\
f_2(x) = e^x -1
$$

The condition number for a function is defined as follows:

$$
k(f) = \left| x \cdot \frac{f'}{f} \right|
$$

Lets analyze conditioning first:

$$
k(f_1) = \frac{x}{x - a},
$$

which means that $f_1$ is **ill-conditioned** near $x = a$;

$$
k(f_2) = \frac{x \cdot e^x}{e^x - 1},
$$

which is undefined near $x = 0$, so lets use L'Hospital:

$$
k(f_2) = \frac{e^x + x \cdot e^x}{e^x},
$$

which means that $f_2$ is **well-conditioned** everywhere (including $x = 0$ proximity).

Now lets analyze stability of these 2 algorithms (if we were to implement them on the computer directly):

$$
\frac{(a - x) \cdot (1 + \epsilon_1) - (a - x)}{a - x} = \epsilon_1,
$$

where $\epsilon_1 \leq \epsilon_m$, and which means that no (numerical) amplification of errors occurs and the algorithm is **stable**;

$$
\frac{(e^x \cdot (1 + \epsilon_1) - 1) \cdot (1 + \epsilon_2) - (e^x - 1)}{e^x - 1} \approx \{\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2 \to 0\} \approx \frac{e^x \cdot \epsilon_1 + (e^x - 1) \cdot \epsilon_2}{e^x - 1} = \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \cdot \frac{e^x}{e^x - 1},
$$

where $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \leq \epsilon_m$, and which means that the algorithm is **unstable** near $x = 0$.

Although everything is allright from the mathematical point of view, i.e. if we obey the formulas and raw theory when obtaining such results, but I begin to doubt in the validity of these results when I try add some logic and reasoning behind it.

First of all, as far as I understand, when we study conditioning of the mathematical problem we think of it in **exact arithmetics** (i.e. we do not think about computers, rounding, floating-point arithmetic, and etc.). Therefore, if I forget for a moment about the result obtained by analyzing $k(f_1)$ and just look on the simple mathematical problem $f_1(x) = a - x$, then I merely don't see how on earth it could be **ill-conditioned** near $x = a$. What is the physical reasoning behind it? What kind of bad thing can happen in **exact arithmetic** near $x = a$?

My curriculum pointed out **cancellation error** as an explanation. What kind of **cancellation error**? From my point of view, there is no such thing as **cancellation error** in **exact arithmetic**...

So, my reason against it would be straightforward, since **ill-condition** implies that **the output changes drastically when the input changes slightly**, then $f_1$ is clearly linear (moreover with coefficient $1$) and any slight changes of $x$ (regardless of whether near $a$ or not) will always result in the **quantitatively equal** change of $y = f_1(x)$ (i.e. $\Delta x \equiv \Delta y$). Therefore, I insist that $f_1$ can in no way be **ill-conditioned** neither at $x = a$ nor anywhere else.

Are there any flaws in my reasoning? Please, clarify this for me as I'm actually stuck on it.

Secondly, why it turns out that $f_2$ is **well-conditioned** while it looks the same as $f_1$? I mean if I follow the same logic as for $f_1$ (i.e. that it's **ill-conditioned** at $x = a$ because of **cancellation** as my curriculum states), then I could say the same here - **ill-conditioned** at $x = 0$, just by looking on the definition of $f_2$! However, mathematics show us that it's not true, but rather that the direct implementation of $f_2$ evaluation on computer would result in **unstable** algorithm. Due to what? I guess now it's **cancellation error** because we are in the floating-point world now. But why?

And still the question is why these two seemingly similar problems are actually so different? I'd really appreciate an exhaustive breakdown of these problems as I feel that I'm missing something very basic and it might prevent my understanding of more challenging phenomena.

Comment: I do not understand your limit $\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2 \rightarrow 0$. Could you please rewrite this?

Comment: When we open brackets we get $\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2$ which goes to zero much faster than $\epsilon_1$ or $\epsilon_2$ alone. Therefore, we can cross their product out.

Comment: Downvoters, please provide comments.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I find it confusing that you describe two equations as "mathematical problems" and then jump to notions of conditioning and "algorithm stability".  Perhaps the problem being addressed is one of root-finding, and it would be worth highlighting this in the first sentence.

Comment: I've only answered the first part because it's unclear to me what you're trying to do with the second part.  To show stability in the simplest case of function evaluation, you could show that each step in an algorithm evaluating the function is well-conditioned, which would require the specification of an algorithm and an analysis of each step.  Maybe I'm just not following your notation and what you're doing, but I don't see that above.

Comment: The other way to investigate algorithm stability is to see how rounding errors behave. Each _atomic_ operation will introduce rounding errors, and eventually it might turn out that your algorithm **blows up** this error, and therefore is **unstable**. In my post you can see that 2 algorithms are analyzed this way and give opposite results. Is it clear?

Comment: @hardmath: And it has nothing to do with root-finding. It's just a general theory on analysis of both algorithm stability and problem conditioning.

Comment: @Haroogan: I'm trying to understand your Question.  What "mathematical problems" are you referring to in your opening sentence?  An equation or function definition is not in itself a problem to be solved.

Comment: @hardmath: It is. It's just a simple problem, that's why you are sort of confused. Finding heat distribution in a square plate is a problem too, but bigger one and involving more steps. It has its own conditioning and stability concerns too. For example, the condition of matrix, and stability of a particular solver. A function - is a problem too, but again the very simple one, and it has its own conditioning. Its evaluation on computer is an algorithm which has stability concerns. It's such a simple and straightforward concept that I'm very surprised why you don't get it.

Comment: @Haroogan: Perhaps your "problem" is function evaluation of the given expressions?  I'm sure it's all very obvious to you, but when people tell you multiple times that your write-up is confusing, it should be considered an opportunity to improve your wording.

Comment: @Haroogan Yes, I understand the concept of stability.  No, I do see in your post that the two function evaluations are analyzed that way.  For instance, $f_1$ requires one and only one operation, and so its stability is identical to its conditioning, so I don't see why you get different results from conditioning vs stability.

Comment: @Ethan Coon: My goodness, you are so wrong. Sorry for complain, but I've lost count how many times I was amazed in the past 2 days on how people here do not know simple things. Googled for you, please have a look at these concise lectures which more or less explain the concept pretty closely to what I'm discussing here: [#1](http://www.cs.usask.ca/~spiteri/M313/notes/Lecture14.pdf) and [#2](http://www.cs.usask.ca/~spiteri/M313/notes/Lecture15.pdf). Especially, pay attention in #2 to the **proof that floating-point subtraction is indeed a stable operation**.

Comment: And remember, _it's the combinations of floating-point operations that are dangerous and can result in unstable algorithm_. **All 4 basic floating-point operations alone are stable**.

Comment: @hardmath: _I can't write a tutorial or a book here_. To my mind, I made detailed question - well-formatted, well-formulated, well-presented, well-defined. If you are not familiar with the concept, or forgot it, or don't feel confident with it at the moment, or forgot the notation, or whatever else, then this question is just not for you. By the way, you are the only one who had a problem with _"problems"_.

Comment: I think your answer is in the paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/roberto/etc_floatingPoint.pdf) by

Comment: @RSFalcon7: I know this paper, read it long time ago, and feel confident with the concepts in it, and beyond. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

(This just addresses the first part of your question).

The subtlety here is in your definition of the condition number -- as defined here, it is a ratio of relative error in the output to relative error in the input ([ie these notes](http://www.math.utk.edu/~ccollins/M577/Handouts/cond_stab.pdf)).  As you've discovered, near $x=a$, the relative error of the input is order $\epsilon$, while the relative error of the output is order $\epsilon / \epsilon = 1$.

The problem is not the function, but your choice of error norms.  For this problem, the relative norm isn't a good choice near $f = 0$.  In basically any other choice of error norm, things would have been better conditioned.  For the case of a problem we know to be well scaled (i.e. all input and output are expected to approximately order 1), we can guess that the absolute error might have been a better choice.  Then we would define a new condition number,

$k_{abs}$ = absolute error output / absolute error input

$k_{abs} = \frac{|f(x_0 + \epsilon) - f(x_0)|}{|(x_0 + \epsilon) - x_0|} \approx |f'(x_0)| = 1 $

which suggests (correctly) that $f_1$ is well-conditioned everywhere.

Take home message: our condition number is dependent upon the choice of error norms, and care is required in the choice of definition in the general case.  You're right to question these sort of things, and subtleties are common and require more thought than just rote application of formulas.

Note that for most real applications, in selecting a valid solution, the norm used is some combination of absolute and relative error for just this reason.

Answer (score 0):

As $f_1$, the bad condition number is completely obvious.

Let us assume that $a = 0$. For large $x$, pertubations do not induce large relative error, so $x+\epsilon / x$ is small for $x$ large. If $x$ gets smaller and smaller, then $1 + \epsilon / x$ is fairly large.

I do not see any problem with that.

Comment: Didn't you mess up the notation? You write a sum of absolute value and its relative perturbation: $x + \frac{\epsilon}{x}$, where $\epsilon$ is absolute perturbation in your notation I suspect, but that's wrong from the physical point of view. I think you should have used either $x \cdot (1 + \epsilon)$ or $x + \Delta x$, where $\epsilon = \frac{\Delta x}{x}$ is relative perturbation, and $\Delta x$ is absolute perturbation.

Comment: @Haroogan: Your notation is not clear. Are you using notation from a book like _Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms_ by Higham? It's not obvious to a general computational science audience what you mean by $\epsilon$ (versus $\Delta{x}$) unless they read your comment, and even then, it could probably stand to be clarified.

Comment: I'm not discussing my notation here. I don't know this book. To people who are involved in computational science everyday the notation I gave is absolutely clear and sort of **conventional**. Yes, there are variations, however even if it's not the notation you are used to, you could still easily infer what's going on if you once again have good CS background.

Comment: Secondly, I have to downvote this obviously wrong answer. I get the point which Martin is trying to draw, but the way he reasons it is false. If you set $a = 0$ - you get completely different case in which you would end up with $k(f_1) \equiv 1$ on the whole domain. Which means that it would be _unconditionally_ **well-conditioned**. It happens because when $a = 0$, essentially what you do is you turn it into $f_1(x) = -x$, and by definition of $k$ it is **well-conditioned** everywhere on the domain.

Comment: @Haroogan: You're the one who brought up notation, and if you are asking a question, it is your duty to communicate what you are asking clearly. Computational science is a diverse field (with diverse notation!), and what is "obvious" to some is not obvious to all.

Comment: My original answer did contain a typo.